# Remove date from Google Search Results Description

Tags: seo

How do I remove the date from the google search results of my posts?

Is this related to WordPress or is it theme-specific?

Comment: I didnt understand. You have some date in your meta description and you want to remove that data from dascription? Can you be more precise? Do you use any SEO plugin?

Comment: I use Wordpress Yoast plugin - for some reason the date of the post is the first thing that appears on the google meta description - i don't know how this is added to the description

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Paste this code in `functions.php`

```
add_filter( 'wpseo_show_date_in_snippet_preview', false); //Returning false on this will prevent the date from showing up in the snippet preview.
```

Note:
[WordPress SEO api](http://yoast.com/wordpress/seo/api/)

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it.

Navigate to **SEO>Titles and Metas** and remove **%%date%%** from **Meta description template** field.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the accepted answer is incorrect. (See 1.)

Below is the working answer I have found. (Sourced here 2.)

```
add_action('wpseo_dc_'.'DC.date.issued', '__return_false'); // Premium only
add_filter( 'wpseo_og_article_published_time', '__return_false' );
add_filter( 'wpseo_og_article_modified_time', '__return_false' );
add_filter( 'wpseo_og_og_updated_time', '__return_false' );
```

1. https://kb.yoast.com/kb/date-appears-search-results/
2. https://gist.github.com/amboutwe/e5b83cd990b5c1bc4015c20f5e3cd754

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it will work

```
// Remove DatePublished
 add_filter( 'wpseo_schema_graph_pieces', 'remove_datePublished_from_schema', 11, 2 );
 add_filter( 'wpseo_schema_webpage', 'remove_datePublished_property_from_webpage', 11, 1 );

 /**
 * Removes the DatePublished graph pieces from the schema collector.
 *
 * @param array  $pieces  The current graph pieces.
 * @param string $context The current context.
 *
 * @return array The remaining graph pieces.
 */
function remove_datePublished_from_schema( $pieces, $context ) {
return \array_filter( $pieces, function( $piece ) {
    return ! $piece instanceof \Yoast\WP\SEO\Generators\Schema\datePublished;
} );

}

/**
 * Removes the DatePublished property from the WebPage piece.
 *
 * @param array $data The WebPage's properties.
 *
 * @return array The modified WebPage properties.
 */
function remove_datePublished_property_from_webpage( $data ) {
if (array_key_exists('datePublished', $data)) {
    unset($data['datePublished']);
}
return $data;

}
```

Comment: Try to add an explanation as to WHY your answer works and how.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).